# Add Multitouch Support in SwiftUI to DragGesture()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, multi-touch

I’m currently working on a `SwiftUI` project where I need to implement true multitouch support on a view that consists of multiple buttons. The existing implementation supports dragging across these buttons to update an `activeButtonIndex` state, highlighting the button currently being dragged over. However, it currently only supports single-touch interactions. I want to enhance this to support multitouch, where multiple buttons can be activated simultaneously if multiple fingers are used.

I would like to maintain all the current functionality. I’m looking for a `SwiftUI`-only solution, without resorting to `UIKit` interop.

I tried referencing Apple’s developer documentation article [Composing SwiftUI gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing-swiftui-gestures) to no avail.

Here’s the simplified version of my current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeButtonIndex: Int? = nil
    @State private var buttonFrames: [CGRect] = Array(repeating: .zero, count: 11)
    private let buttonCount = 11
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            activeButtonView
            buttonsView
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    private var activeButtonView: some View {
        Text("Active Button \(activeButtonIndex.map { "\n\($0 + 1)" } ?? "\nNone")")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding()
    }
    
    private var buttonsView: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< buttonCount, id: \.self) { index in
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 210)
                    .background(backgroundForButton(at: index))
                    .overlay(GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear.onAppear {
                            buttonFrames[index] = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func backgroundForButton(at index: Int) -> Color {
        activeButtonIndex == index ? .green : .blue
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { value in
                updateActiveButton(with: value.location)
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                activeButtonIndex = nil
            }
    }
    
    private func updateActiveButton(with location: CGPoint) {
        for (index, frame) in buttonFrames.enumerated() {
            if frame.contains(location) {
                activeButtonIndex = index
                return
            }
        }
        activeButtonIndex = nil
    }
}
```

Has anyone implemented something similar or can guide me on how to approach adding multitouch support in this context? Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Interactive demo of drag gesture prototype.]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `simultaneousGesture`?
I think this will help for multi-touch-support.

```swift
VStack(spacing: 100) {
    Text("First button")
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { _ in
                    print("First button is dragging")
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    print("First button tapped")
                }
        )
    
    Text("Second button")
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { _ in
                    print("Second button is dragging")
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    print("Second button tapped")
                }
        )
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried with `.simultaneousGesture()` but managed to get only halfway there by supporting additional taps with other fingers, but not simultaneous multi-drags.

Comment: @Tzar I added `.onChanged` and it seems multi-dragging works fine to me. Could you try with this code in a clean project?

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Can you modify the code example I provided, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: You are using only one `dragGesture`, but you need multiple dragGesture for every single button.
If you have only one `dragGesture`, there is no way to recognize multiple finger gesture in my opinion.